# How to append the array to a legend in Jqplot?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jqplot

I have an Array .I want to append it to the Legend labels in Jqplot chart.

```
var temps = [];  
temps[0] = "Ax";  
temps[1] = "Bx";  
temps[2] = "Cx";  
temps[3] = "Dx";  
 opts{  
legend: {  
renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,  
show: true,  
showLabels: true,  
//labels: ['Ax', 'Bx', 'Cx','Dx'] - this will exactly work
labels: [temps]  //Append array .It Won't working.
},  
 };
```

Comment: i was the first who provided the solution. :) Please look at time.

Comment: Thank you :):) @ Alexandru-Ionut Mihai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to use simply:** `labels: temps`.

`temps` is already an array.

Answer (score 1):

**Try with no [ ]**
like `labels : temps`